# sending mail with attachment using gmail api in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail-api

When I'm trying to send mail using php.text also send as an attachment with the name noname.html. please provide a solution for me.
I have used this library to send email https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. My code is like this.any help will be appreciated.

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']);            
    $objGMail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

   $strMailContent = 'This is a test mail which is <b>sent via</b> using Gmail API client library.<br/><br/><br/>Thanks,<br/><b>Premjith K.K..</b>';
   // $strMailTextVersion = strip_tags($strMailContent, '');

    $strRawMessage = "";
    $boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';
    $strToMailName = 'NAME';
    $strToMail = 'name@gmail.com';
    $strSesFromName = 'Premjith GMAIL API';
    $strSesFromEmail = 'premji341800@gmail.com';
    $strSubject = 'Test mail using GMail API - with attachment - ' . date('M d, Y h:i:s A');

    $strRawMessage .= 'To: ' .$strToMailName . " <" . $strToMail . ">" . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'From: '.$strSesFromName . " <" . $strSesFromEmail . ">" . "\r\n";

    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";

    $filePath = 'abc.pdf';
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
    $fileName = 'abc.pdf';
    $fileData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath));

    $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: '. $mimeType .'; name="'. $fileName .'";' . "\r\n";            
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-ID: <' . $strSesFromEmail . '>' . "\r\n";            
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: ' . $fileName . ';' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"; size=' . filesize($filePath). ';' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)), 76, "\n") . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";

    $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . "\r\n\r\n";
   // $strRawMessage .= $strMailTextVersion . "\r\n";

    $strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";

    //Send Mails
    //Prepare the message in message/rfc822
    try {
        // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
        $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($mime);
        $objSentMsg = $objGMail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);

        print('Message sent object');
       // print($objSentMsg);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print($e->getMessage());
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
```

When I change the code line
 `$strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";` 
to
 `$strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Alternative; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";` Mail Send as html only with out attachment. Please help me

Comment: Why don't you just use phpmailer?

Comment: Codeiginter has built in email library

Comment: Need Gmail authentication and need to send mail using logined employee account.

Comment: I think the first code was correct, **`Content-type: Multipart/Mixed`**. You can also check the tutorial [send mail through Gmail API](https://www.pipiscrew.com/2015/04/php-send-mail-through-gmail-api/) and related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012226/5995040). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, I have referred that two links you have provided and it can visible in my code. but the mail sending body also as the attachment with the name noname.html.

Comment: Hi anybody please help me on thisI'm unable to fix it till now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have change my code like this its worked fine for me. Thank you all for the support.

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']);            
    $objGMail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

   $strMailContent = 'This is a test mail which is <b>sent via</b> using Gmail API client library.<br/><br/><br/>Thanks,<br/><b>Premjith K.K..</b>';
   // $strMailTextVersion = strip_tags($strMailContent, '');

    $strRawMessage = "";
    $boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';
    $strToMailName = 'NAME';
    $strToMail = 'name@gmail.com';
    $strSesFromName = 'Premjith GMAIL API';
    $strSesFromEmail = 'premji341800@gmail.com';
    $strSubject = 'Test mail using GMail API - with attachment - ' . date('M d, Y h:i:s A');

    $strRawMessage .= 'To: ' .$strToMailName . " <" . $strToMail . ">" . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'From: '.$strSesFromName . " <" . $strSesFromEmail . ">" . "\r\n";

    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";

    $filePath = 'abc.pdf';
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
    $fileName = 'abc.pdf';
    $fileData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath));

    $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: '. $mimeType .'; name="'. $fileName .'";' . "\r\n";            
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-ID: <' . $strSesFromEmail . '>' . "\r\n";            
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: ' . $fileName . ';' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"; size=' . filesize($filePath). ';' . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)), 76, "\n") . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";

    //Send Mails
    //Prepare the message in message/rfc822
    try {
        // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
        $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($mime);
        $objSentMsg = $objGMail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);

        print('Message sent object');
       // print($objSentMsg);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print($e->getMessage());
        unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine for me but now what every text I put in as the body of the email it's converted into Chinese character. do anyone have solution?

Comment: how to add multiple to recipient and multiple cc, bcc, as well as multiple attachments ?

Answer (score 2):

The above code works fine for a single attachment.

If you want to send multiple attachments just follow this code this allowed to send your mail body part with multiple attachments.

```
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']);            
$objGMail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$strMailContent = 'This is a test mail which is <b>sent via</b> using Gmail API client library.<br/><br/><br/>Thanks,<br/><b>Premjith K.K..</b>';
$strRawMessage = "";
$boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
$subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';
$strToMailName = 'NAME';
$strToMail = 'name@gmail.com';
$strSesFromName = 'Premjith GMAIL API';
$strSesFromEmail = 'premji341800@gmail.com';
$strSubject = 'Test mail using GMail API - with attachment - ' . date('M d, Y h:i:s A');

$strRawMessage .= 'To: ' .$strToMailName . " <" . $strToMail . ">" . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'From: '.$strSesFromName . " <" . $strSesFromEmail . ">" . "\r\n";

$strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?' . $subjectCharset . '?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . "\r\n\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= $sentMailData->body . "\r\n";
$strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";

foreach ($files as $key => $filePath) {
    if($filePath!=""){
        $array = explode('/', $filePath);
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
        $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
        $fileName = $array[sizeof($array)-1];
        $fileData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath));

        $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: '. $mimeType .'; name="'. $fileName .'";' . "\r\n";            
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-ID: <' . $sentMailData->email. '>' . "\r\n";            
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Description: ' . $fileName . ';' . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"; size=' . filesize($filePath). ';' . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath)), 76, "\n") . "\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= "--{$boundary}\r\n";
    }
}

//Send Mails
//Prepare the message in message/rfc822
try {
    // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    $objSentMsg = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($objSentMsg); echo '</pre>';
    if($sentMailData->attachments!=""){
        $files = explode(',', $sentMailData->attachments);
        foreach ($files as $key => $filePath) {
            if($filePath!=""){
                @unlink($filePath);
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($sentMailData); echo '</pre>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Please note the `$fileData` here is unnecessary as the file is read in the foreach loop.