# how to share image with gmail share in body

Tags: php, gmail, share, gmail-api

I want share image with gmail share in body.

```
$body_link = '<img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/address.png" />';
$email =  urlencode($body_link);
<a title="Google+" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&su=Refer your friend&body=<?php echo $email; ?>" target="_BLANK">gmail</a>
```

My gmail screen is:
    [image]

After send gmail, on my gmail screen:
    [image]

Why not getting image in mail?

And is it possible?

Comment: because you told the browser to insert that literal text into the email. It won't be interpreted as HTML and then rendered (because apart from anything, Gmail might consider that a security risk).

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: And is it possible?

Comment: No. Read the bit of my last comment which is in brackets again.

Comment: If you really want to interact with Gmail in a more complex way, I suggest using the Gmail API.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the image as attachment and then create the email with the attachment on the body.

You can follow the [Creating messages with attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments) documentation and apply it to PHP.

I you send yourself an email with an image in the body and you check Show original (Next to Reply, click More and then Show original.) from that email, you can see how the image is set as an attachment.

This post can help you also: [sending mail with attachment using gmail api in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378400/sending-mail-with-attachment-using-gmail-api-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top)